# Custom Path to the DisplayTemplates folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

For some reasons I want to move the DisplayTemplates folder from the standard path to a new one.

Standard:
 ~/views/shared/DisplayTemplates

I want
~/MVC/views/shared/DisplayTemplates

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: @Stephen-Muecke
This is a special folder "DisplayTemplates" that is used for e.g
@Html.DisplayForx(x=> x.name, "MyVersionOfStringPresentation") 
To enable custom rendering. 
The "Duplicate" you are refering to is actually not answering my question

Comment: Did you have question?